# Show a block only in in the front page and not in every pager page

Tags: blocks, 9

I configured a block to be shown only on the front page, but the front page is actually a view of the last published nodes, with a pager, and the block is shown on each of its pages.

Is there any convenient way to show the block only once? I know it is possible to write a hook that checks if the *page* parameter is set and hide the block in that case.

What hook should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom @Condition plugin, where the result is true when on the first page, and false whenever a URL parameter exists for page. Then you could set this context as the block context.

I wrote a tutorial on creating custom @Condition plugins here: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/custom-drupal-block-visibility-plugins-and-condition-plugin-api